# How do I get my INTERSECT code to include all rows?

Tags: sql

I am working with two tables:

Table1

```
Name    Team    ID
Robinho Brazil  1
Ronaldo Brazil  2
Totti   Italy   3
Baggio  Italy   4
Rooney  England 5
```

Table2

```
ID  Football_Club   Address
1   Chelsea         London
3   Fulham          London
```

I would like a new table with all columns included but to only include the two rows where the two tables intersect. I am using the following SQL Query which is very wrong:

```
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       team
FROM   table1
INTERSECT
SELECT id,
       football_club,
       address
FROM   table2
```

How can I rewrite this to bring about the correct result using INTERSECT?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (I.e. add the expected result too.)

Comment: You probably want a JOIN, not INTERSECT.

Comment: Is the INTERSECT function only used for one column usually?

Comment: Usually with same/similar sets of columns. (And team is quite different from address.)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an `INNER JOIN` rather than an `INTERSECT`. Replace `*` with the columns you need using the table aliases.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```